# No matching function call when passing iterators as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, containers

I want to create a Sum() function that calculates the sum of a STL container. The function uses the template argument for the iterator type and accepts two iterators as arguments as below:

```
template <typename T>
double Sum(typename T::const_iterator start, typename T::const_iterator end)
{
    typename T::const_iterator i3;
    double sum2=0.0;
    for (i3=start; i3 != end; ++i3)
    {
        sum2 += (i3);
    }
    return sum2;
}
```

and in the main() I call the function like:

```
vector<double>::const_iterator vec_start=myvector.begin();
vector<double>::const_iterator vec_end=myvector.end();
cout<<"The sum of the vector is "<<Sum(vec_start, vec_end)<<endl;
```

But it says that no matching function call for Sum(). I read some discussions that it's because the function signature is T but I pass iterators and that I need to specify data type before passing iterator parameters.

Comment: Are there any reasons against std::accumulate?

Comment: No just a homework practicing container iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the discussions you've found said, the template parameter `T` can't be deduced automatically because of [non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), so you need to specify it explicitly. e.g.

```
cout << "The sum of the vector is " << Sum<vector<double>>(vec_start, vec_end) << endl;
//                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But you don't need to do that in fact, you could change the declaration of `Sum` to:

```
template <typename I>
double Sum(I start, I end)
{
    I i3;
    double sum2=0.0;
    for (i3=start; i3 != end; ++i3)
    {
        sum2 += *i3;
    }
    return sum2;
}
```

`I` could be deduced then it's fine to use it originally as

```
cout << "The sum of the vector is " << Sum(vec_start, vec_end) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see the logic now:)

Comment: don't you mean `*i3` instead of `(i3)`? An iterator is usually dereferenced to obtain the value it refers to.